# Invalid route in angular 6 throwing uncaught exception

Tags: typescript, angular6

Putting a script tag along with my route param throwing an exception

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'product-listing/:language/:country', component: ProductFinderShellComponent },
  { path: 'product-listing/:language', redirectTo: '/error' },
  { path: 'product-listing', redirectTo: '/product-finder/en/us', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

url tried:

```
http://localhost:4200/product-listing/en/us<script>alert('hi')</script>
```

Error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: ''hi''
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: ''hi''
```

All helps are appreciated. Tia

Answer (score 0):

You should use `encodeURIComponent` for prevent special character in URL

```
let param = encodeURIComponent('us<script>alert('hi')</script>'));
let url = 'http://localhost:4200/product-listing/en/' + param;
```

Comment: urls are inserting by the user, we dont have a control over there. Our requirement is to show the current route even though user entered an invalid url like http://localhost:4200/product-listing/en/us<script>alert('hi')</script>. Currently it is going to a white page.